# Continuity of Delta in Delta-Epsilon Argument

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity, epsilon-delta

This is a strange question but I am interested to know in this problem.

Let $\Omega \subset\mathbb{R}^{N}$ be a bounded smooth domain. Assume $f : \overline{\Omega}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Then, we have the following definition :
$$\forall x \in \overline{\Omega}, \forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists \delta(x,\varepsilon) > 0 \ni |x-y|<\delta(x,\varepsilon)\implies|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$$

Now, my question is, since $\overline{\Omega}$ is a compact set, can we always find $\delta(x,\varepsilon)>0$ so that it becomes a continuous function with respect to $x$ and $\varepsilon$?

For simple function like $y=mx+c$ in one-dimensional case for finite interval $[a,b]$ the question is trivial but I am not sure about $N$-dimensional case with arbitrary continuous function.

Comment: $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ or $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$?

Comment: How does $\Omega$ compact follow from bounded + smooth? Or should it be $\bar{\Omega}$ compact?

Comment: I don't think $\delta(x,\epsilon)$ is a well-defined function from $\Omega \times(0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$. If $\delta(x,\epsilon)$ works for a given $x$ and $\epsilon$ then so does $\delta/2$. So, how should one define the mapping $(x,\epsilon)\mapsto \delta(x,\epsilon)$?

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification, I have fixed the assumptions.

But can we define $\delta(x,\varepsilon)$ so that it becomes continuous? I understand that $\delta(x,\varepsilon)$ is not unique

Comment: Single-valued functions of any number of variables must satisfy the uniqueness of output per input property. So, you cannot even define $\delta(x,\epsilon)$ as a function let alone ask for continuity. But if you had multi-valued functions in mind from the start then it's beyond my realm, sorry.